# Is there a way to type into textbox on HTML webpage?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names in excel for which I am trying to search on White pages to get the name of the city  for which they live in, and then write the name of their city back into excel.

My problem is that I can't write their name into the text box to perform a search. (See pic below) I have copied the text box code here as well

[image]
[image]

I have the following code written:

```
Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
ieObj.Visible = True
ieObj.navigate "https://www.whitepages.com/person"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")


For Each Name In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    FullName = Cells(Row, Column_B).Value & " " & Cells(Row, Column_A).Value
    
    ieObj.document.getElementById("input-97146989").Value = FullName 
    
    Row = Row + 1
Next
```

EDIT:

```
Sub RetrieveInfo()

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")


'Column A has the first name and column B has all the last names. We
'need to concatenate these two elements together

Dim FirstName
Dim LastName

Dim FullName
Dim Column_A
Dim Column_B

Column_A = 1
Column_B = 2

Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement

With ws

Row = 2

Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Dim html As HTMLDocument

'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "https://www.whitepages.com"



Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
    
DoEvents

Loop

Set html = ie.document

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName(“v - Text - field__slot”)


Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long
count = 0
For Each element In elements
    If element.className = "input-83892401" Then
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next element


For Each Name In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    FullName = Cells(Row, Column_B).Value & " " & Cells(Row, Column_A).Value
    

    
    Row = Row + 1
Next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to guess those ID's are created when the page loads so that they are different every time, in an attempt to prevent you from doing what you want to do, since when I load the page, there is no input box with that exact ID.

Comment: See if you can select the container DIV and then you can parse its contents for the ID to use instead.

Comment: Im not quite sure what container DIV means exactly. Sorry im new to VBA

Comment: Well a DIV is HTML, not VBA... the DIV is the line right before the INPUT line that you have highlighted. See how it has a CLASS and not an ID? So you would use `getElementsByClassName` instead. In short, this is not going to be simple if you are not already familiar with HTML and VBA.

Comment: Well...guess im going to have to learn...Thanks for your help too. Much appreciated. I replaced "ieObj.document.getElementById("input-97146989").Value = FullName" to "ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("input-97146989").Value = FullName" but im still getting an error.

Comment: `input-97146989` is not the class name of the div. That's the ID of the INPUT tag. You have to change that too - and then you will need to parse the array it returns and find that INPUT tag that you want. You aren't going to be able to just change one line of code and make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to parse the array and return the input.

Comment: im not sure if I'm on the right track, but this is what I came up with so far: (see above edits)

Answer (score 1):

Your are close, so try it like this:

```
' fixed the quotes and the string that had too many spaces in it
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("v-text-field__slot")

Dim nStart As Integer
For Each element In elements
    If InStr(element.innerHTML, "input-") > 0 Then
        ' this will print the innerHTML for each element to the debug window
        ' Debug.Print element.innerHTML

        ' this will show all the ID values
        nStart = InStr(element.innerHTML, "id=") + 4
        Debug.Print Mid$(element.innerHTML, nStart, InStr(nStart, element.innerHTML, " ") - nStart - 1)

    End If
Next
```

Note, this does not do everything you want, it just shows you how to figure out what the ID's are that they are using. I can delete it as an answer later?

And once you know the ID...

```
Dim sID as String
sID = Mid$(element.innerHTML, nStart, InStr(nStart, element.innerHTML, " ") - nStart - 1)
ieObj.document.getElementById(sID).Value = FullName
```

Someone else could probably explain this better, but until then, this should at least give you some more things to try.

Comment: `ieObject.document,querySelector("input[id^='input']")` `querySelectoAll` to gather all matches.